# How to pass multiple values from URL to r shiny checkbox input

Tags: r, url, shiny

Please see the sample code below, what I want is just pass multiple ***chk*** values from url as shiny check box input values; it works for single value like: **http://127.0.0.1:3471/?chk=1**
but it does not work for multiple values like **http://127.0.0.1:3471/?chk=1,2**.
Thanks in advance.

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
    ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(    
    checkboxGroupInput("chk", "Check box", c("Monthly" = 1,
                                           "Quarterly" = 2,
                                           "Weekly" = 3,
                                           "Daily" = 4))

    )),

      server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
      observe({
      query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)

      if (!is.null(query[['chk']])) {
        print(query[['chk']])
        updateTextInput(session, "chk", value = query[['chk']])
      }
     })
    })
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may want to use `updateCheckboxGroupInput` to update your checkboxes instead of `updateTextInput`.

The extracted `query[['chk']]` will be a string separated by comma containing elements you wish to update in your checkboxes. You can use `strsplit` to separate them (and `unlist` since result would be a list).

```
server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[['chk']])) {
      print(query[['chk']])
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "chk", selected = unlist(strsplit(query[['chk']], ",")))
    }
  })
})
```